# How to deserialize a map of string keys and numbers or string values as a HashMap<String, String> with serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I have a single level `json` where the values are of `i32`s, `f32`s, and `String`s.
How to deserialize that `json` to `HashMap<String, String>`?

```rust
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": 0,
    "key3": 6.7
}
```

How to deserialize it? Is there a way in `serde` that can help here?

```rust
let json: HashMap<String, String>= serde_json::from_str(r#"{"key1": "value1", "key2": 0, "key3": 6.7}"#).unwrap();
```

---

**Edit**

I'm wondering if there is a way provided by `serde` like a flag to avoid the overhead due to the additional iteration.

Comment: Since you deleted your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181447/how-to-deserialize-a-field-of-a-struct-with-serdedefault-path-using-a-m) instead of allowing it to be marked as a duplicate (duplicates are not bad!), here's [the solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b1313f7f0d649984a82b6d566d53941).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what the Rust strings should contain. This solution will keep the value part exactly like they are in JSON, including trailing digits and quotes around the string. This is the result of running this code:

```
[src/main.rs:15] map = {
    "key1": "\"value1\"",
    "key2": "0",
    "key3": "6.7",
    "key4": "0.000",
}
```

```rust
use serde::de::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let j = r#"
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": 0,
        "key3": 6.7,
        "key4": 0.000
    }"#;

    let mut deser = serde_json::Deserializer::from_str(j);
    let map = deser_hashmap(&mut deser).unwrap();
    dbg!(map);
}

fn deser_hashmap<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<HashMap<String, String>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct MapVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MapVisitor {
        type Value = HashMap<String, String>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("a map")
        }

        fn visit_map<A>(self, mut access: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: MapAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut values = HashMap::new();

            // We use RawValue here to access the JSON value exactly as it is occuring in the input.
            while let Some((key, value)) = (access.next_entry())?
                .map(|(k, v): (String, &'de serde_json::value::RawValue)| (k, v.get().to_owned()))
            {
                values.insert(key, value);
            }

            Ok(values)
        }
    }

    let visitor = MapVisitor;
    deserializer.deserialize_map(visitor)
}
```

[Code on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb937c79f2aec084c2583587ca06fc9c)

Answer (score 4):

we can workaround by:

```
let str = r#"{"three": "123", "one": 1, "two": 12}"#;
    let map:HashMap<String,serde_json::Value> = serde_json::from_str(str).unwrap();
    let out_map:HashMap<String,String> = map.iter().map(|val| ( a.0.to_string() , a.1.to_string()) ) .collect();
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way provided by `serde` like a flag

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know up front the type of a valud, you can use built in `Value` data structure.

`Value` represents JSON:

```rust
enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

So you can do next:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{Result, Value};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let s = r#"{"three": "2", "one": 1, "two": 12}"#;

    // Object({"one": Number(1), "three": String(2), "two": Number(12)})
    let data: Value = serde_json::from_str(&s)?;
    
    // OR
    {
       let data: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&s)?;
    }
    println!("Hello {:?}", data.get("one"));
    Ok(())
}
```